# What happened to the @stackchess Twitter account?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if [@stackchess](https://twitter.com/stackchess) is an official Twitter account for Chess SE but there are links in the edit parts of the posts to this Twitter account so I assume it is official.

It seems to be suspended for me, is it really or is this a regional thing for me?

If it is, then why was it suspended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue came up about a year ago on the main Meta as well. I'm quoting an [answer by @double-beep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358514/295232):

> It seems that Twitter suddenly and randomly started blocking those accounts because they were bots posting automated tweets and that resulted in SE [not creating new Twitter accounts for new sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548) since 2015. It's still not known why Twitter has deleted [only some of the accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358449/why-is-stackchess-account-blocked-on-twitter/358514#comment1197036_358449).